# How to use locale independent decimal and numeric separator in format string?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, string-formatting

I am using the following to format a column value (bound to value of type decimal?):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
```

I want to now change it to the following format :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###.00##}")]
```

But, this isn't locale independent as I am hard coding decimal and numeric separator. Basically, I want to display a string with appropriate numeric and decimal separators. Also, I want minimum two zeros after decimal separator and maximum of 4 zeros.
Is it possible to specify such a string at **compile-time?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But, this isn't locale independent as I am hard coding decimal and numeric separator

No you aren't; in format specifiers the `.` and `,` mean "decimal separator" and "thousands separator" respectively, not literal commas and periods. It should work correctly. For example, '#,###.00##' in a fr-FR culture should come out as "1 234,56":

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr");
decimal d = 1234.56M;
string s = d.ToString("#,###.00##'", culture); // "1 234,56"
```